# Format NumeralJS percentages without multiplying by 100

Tags: formatting, handsontable

In Handsontable, you can use the `format` option on a `numeric` cell to format the values accordingly. Since it uses NumeralJS, I looked through the documentation to see how to format a number to just add the % sign and not multiply by 100 but can't find how to do this without setting my own.

Example cell:

```
{
    "type": "numeric",
    "format": "0.00%"
}
```

When the value is 7, it displays `"700.00%"`. I'd like it to show `"7.00%". Any way of doing this in handsontable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think there is a way to do this currently without making changes to the **numeral.js** file.

If you want, you can edit `function formatPercentage` (found in **numberal.js**) by removing the `* 100` part:

```
function formatPercentage (n, format, roundingFunction) {
    var space = '',
        output,
        value = n._value/* * 100*/; // comment out or remove * 100 here

    ...
}
```

Comment: Alright, good to know. I ended up formatting it manually with regex using a custom renderer but this would work too.

Comment: Unfortunately I had to resort to modifying numeral.js.

Comment: Pushed a PR, but I'm not too optimistic when looking at the number of unmerged PRs.

Answer (score 6):

For anyone still looking for the easiest way of achieving this, there is a numeral option you can set like so:

```
numeral.options.scalePercentBy100 = false;
```

Credit to [Csaba Toth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/292502/csaba-toth) for creating the PR.
[PR Here](https://github.com/adamwdraper/Numeral-js/pull/446)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps better than overriding numeral JS logic, you could also just numeral the number to the decimal precision you want and then concatenate the percent symbol at the end.

```
formatPercent(number) {
    return `${numeral(number).format('0.00')}%`;
}
```